# Ubuntu 14.04 crouton Chrome OS wifi and network issue

Tags: networking, wireless, google-chrome, chromeos

I've just installed Ubuntu on my Toshiba Chromebook 2 using crouton. It updated to 14.04 very quickly.

I have 2 main issues:

I'm automatically connected to my wifi network, just as I am when I switch back to Chrome OS. However, I wasn't able to see any wireless network options anywhere in Ubuntu. From another help thread, I was advised to enter:

```
sudo apt-get intall indicator-applet indicator-network
```

I did this and I now see a Wi-Fi icon on the top of the screen, however it's empty and nothing happens when I click on it. I'm still connected to my home network but am unable to connect to any other network.

Does anyone else know how to fix this?

Also, perhaps I should put this in another thread but I can't connect to my NAS on my home network. I was previously connecting to it via a MacBook. When I look at the drive properties on the MacBook, it shows the path as `afp://MyBookWorld`....

Is the problem that it's `AFP` (Apple Filing Protocol)? Apple-specific? Any way I can connect to it? It doesn't show up in *Browse Network*, it just gives an error saying `Failing to retrieve share list from the network`.

I'm new to Linux and not familiar with the command line, apart from a few basic commands I have picked up on forums.

Really want to get the NAS access sorted, as this is the last hurdle preventing me from moving to Ubuntu for most of my needs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is crouton?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I believe crouton is offtopic here ;) Try android

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: The Crouton boot process is off topic here but everything that isn't specific to Crouton remains on topic here.

Comment: @DavidFoerster This is crouton specific and is a perfect example of how crouton questions (beyond the bootloader) are off topic because crouton runs in a chroot and is not actually a bootloader. This is why there is no access to hardware and no output from lspci.

Answer (score 1):

Seems https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/611 has [some direction](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/248).

It is not a very optimistic chance though:

> you'll probably first need to stop Chromium OS's shill service (sudo
>   stop shill). Remember that initctl (upstart) always controls Chromium
>   OS's services, since Chromium OS owns the init process, so you may
>   need to launch whatever networking system daemon manually. There's no
>   known procedure for getting NM working inside a chroot (and again, I
>   don't recommend it), but have fun paving the way.